# Enums with interface - how to do so generically?

Tags: java, interface, enums

If I have a set of enums, and want to have them all implement an interface, is this the correct way to do generically?

Enum:

```
public enum MentalSkill implements SkillType {
    ACADEMICS,COMPUTER,CRAFTS,INVESTIGATION,MEDICINE,OCCULT,POLITICS,SCIENCE;
    private static final int UNTRAINED_PENALTY = -3;
    @Override
    public SkillType fromValue(String value) {
        return valueOf(value);
    }
    @Override
    public int getUntrainedPenalty() {
        return UNTRAINED_PENALTY;
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface SkillType {

SkillType fromValue(String value);  
int getUntrainedPenalty();
}
```

Holding Class (where my suspcions lie that this is not quite right):

```
public class SkillsSet<T extends SkillType> {
    T t;
    Map<T,Integer> skills = new HashMap<>();
    public SkillsSet(String[] skills) {
        for (String string : skills) {
            addSkill(string,t.getUntrainedPenalty());
        }
    }
    private void addSkill(String skillString,Integer value) {
        skills.put((T) t.fromValue(skillString), 0);
    }
}
```

The issue comes in my `T t` which will obviously give a NPE as I don't instantiate my inferred type. The issue is that I can't, as it's an enum.

What's the Java way of saying 'Use this interface to access an enum method generically.'? Throwing in `skills.put(T.fromValue(skillString), 0);` doesn't work, which was my next guess.

I've looked over the tutorials (which is how I've gotten this far) and I couldn't seem to see how to get any further. How do I get this code to work?

Comment: Why don't you pass in a `T[]` instead of a `String[]`?

Comment: Because I can't store T[] on file,  but I can with strings in a text document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is through using reflection. I'm not sure if there are other solutions that might look cleaner though. The following does compile and run though.

```
public class SkillsSet<T extends SkillType> { 
    private Map<T,Integer> skills = new HashMap<>();

    // These don't have to be class members, they could be passed
    // around as parameters
    private T[] enumConstants;   // needed only for getEnumValue
    private Class<T> enumClass;  // needed only for getEnumValueAlternate

    public SkillsSet(String[] skills, Class<T> enumClass) {
        // Though all implementers of SkillType are currently enums, it is safer
        // to do some type checking before we do any reflection things
        enumConstants = enumClass.getEnumConstants();
        if (enumConstants == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("enumClass is not an enum");

        for (String string : skills) {
            T t = getEnumValue(string)
            if (t == null) {
                // or use continue if you dont want to throw an exception
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            this.skills.put(t, t.getPenalty());
        }
    }

    // These don't even need to be methods, but I separated them for clarity.
    // SuppressWarnings annotation is used since we checked types in the constructor
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    public T getEnumValue( String string ) {
        try {
            return (T) enumConstants[0].fromValue(string);
        }

        // If valueOf does not find a match, it throws IllegalArgumentExecption
        catch ( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // An alternate version  of getEnumValue that does not require the 'fromValue'
    // method on the SkillType interface.
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    public T getEnumValueAlternate( String string ) {
        try {
            return (T) enumClass.getMethod("valueOf", String.class).invoke(null, string)
        }

        // Any reflection exceptions are treated as 'not found' on valueOf
        catch (Exception e) {
            return null; 
        }
    }


    ...
}
```

There are two different versions of `getEnumValue`. I'd recommend the version that uses the `getEnumConstants` method on the `enumClass` parameter. It also allows you to handle special cases in `fromValue` that might not typically match the enum's `valueOf` function.

Instantiating the above works with
`SkillsSet<MentalSkill> = new SkillsSet<MentalSkill>(new String[] {"COMPUTER", "CRAFTS"}, MentalSkill.class);`

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies in `SkillType` - it should be generic:

```
public interface SkillType<T extends SkillType<T>> {

    T fromValue(String value);  

    int getUntrainedPenalty();
}
```

This is called a *self referencing* generic parameter.

Without this self reference, you could return an instance of a *different* class from the `fromValue()` method.

Here's how it would look:

```
public enum MentalSkill implements SkillType<MentalSkill> {
    public MentalSkill fromValue(...) {}
    ...
}
```

And

```
public class SkillsSet<T extends SkillType<T>> {
    ...
}
```

Once you make this change, it should all fall into place.

Comment: This looks better, but it won't run even with this change.

Comment: I've seen the "self referencing generic parameter" pattern used but didn't know the name for it.

Answer (score 2):

> The issue comes in my T t which will obviously give a NPE as I don't instantiate my inferred type. The issue is that I can't, as it's an enum.

Actually, you couldn't even if it was a "regular" class!  It is not possible to create instances of a parameter type within a generic class ... unless you pass in a `Class<T>` object as an explicit parameter.

In the case of an `enum`, you would either need to pass in a value of the `enum`, or pass in the `Class<T>` for the `enum` and use the static `Enum<T>.valueOf(Class<T>, String)` method to do a lookup.

Something like this would be needed ....

```
public class SkillsSet<T extends SkillType> {
    T t;
    Map<T,Integer> skills = new HashMap<>();
    public SkillsSet(String[] skills, T t) {
        this.t = t;
        for (String string : skills) {
            addSkill(string, t.getUntrainedPenalty());
        }
    }
    private void addSkill(String skillString, Integer value) {
        skills.put((T) t.fromValue(skillString), value);
    }
}
```

But the `skills` map doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  Why would you use the "untrained penalty" for one `T` instance to initialise the skill value for all of the skills?  It makes more sense if it is something more like this:

```
public class SkillsSet<T extends SkillType> { 
    private Map<T,Integer> skills = new HashMap<>();
    public SkillsSet(String[] skills, Class<T> enumClass) {
        for (String string : skills) {
            T t = Enum<T>.valueOf(enumClass, string);
            skills.put(t, t.getUntrainedPenalty());
        }
    }
    // Methods for accessing / updating the skills map information ...
}
```

You would instantiate a `SkillSet` like this:

```
SkillSet<MentalSkill> st = new SkillSet<>(new String[]{"COMPUTER", "OCCULT"},
                                          MentalSkill.class);
```

(Note: this is all uncompiled / untested code!!!)

Note that your `fromValue` method is unnecessary if you have a `Class<T>` object and you so that you can call `Enum<T>.valueOf(...)`.  And it is conceptually a bit odd.  (You are using one instance of `T` as a factory object for other instances of `T`.)

Comment: This looks more promising than I was hoping for!

Comment: @Pureferret - Check that it all compiles.  If it does, I'm fairly confident it will work.

Comment: This code doesn't compile, my Java/Eclipse doesn't recognise Enum<T> (in the line `T t =  Enum<T>.valueOf(enumClass, string)`), even if I explicitly import it. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: now valueOf is complaining about a bound mismatch. `Inferred type  T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Enum<T>` I've tried other toes in both the method call,  and on the type and nothing seems 'valid'.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
@Override
public SkillType fromValue(String value) {
    return valueOf(value);
}
```

the method `valueOf(value)` is a static one, it's not associated with an enum instance, which means you cannot call it generically. What you can do:

```
public class SkillsSet<T extends SkillType> {
    T t = MentalSkill.values()[0];
    Map<T,Integer> skills = new HashMap<>();

    public SkillsSet(String[] skills) {
        for (String string : skills) {
            addSkill(string,t.getUntrainedPenalty());
        }
    }

    private void addSkill(String skillString,Integer value) {
        skills.put((T) t.fromValue(skillString), 0);
    }
}
```

or more clearly

```
public class SkillsSet<T extends SkillType> {
    Map<T,Integer> skills = new HashMap<>();

    public SkillsSet(String[] skills) {
        for (String string : skills) {
            addSkill(string,t.getUntrainedPenalty());
        }
    }

    private void addSkill(String skillString,Integer value) {
        skills.put(MentalSkill.valueOf(skillString), 0);
    }
}
```

If you plan to have more enum types that implement `SkillType` then you need a factory over these types. However in this case, enum probably is not the best design decision.

Comment: The problem with these "solutions" is that you are wiring in a specific `SkillType`.  I suspect that they will give you compilation errors.  For example, `MentalSkill.values()[0]` gives a `MentalSkills` value, which is not necessarily an instance of the `T` that you instantiated `SkillSet` with,